# Is the Maison Liban continuing to hide in the modern era necessary?

Tags: world-of-darkness, lore, vampire-the-masquerade, mage-the-ascension

There is apparently an underground hidden faction of mortals magic-users in Mage the Assension, that is titled the "Maison Liban".

Them having the following origins:

> An underground mystical order that largely consists of Sorcerers,
> Maison Liban has lineage that traces back to House Tremere. Following
> the destruction of House Deidne and the the betrayal of Goratrix,
> Mathieu de Calice left the order. De Calice, who was once an
> apprentice of Goratrix, lead his order of sorcerers into obscurity.
> Whilst the Tremere struggled with their new forms, Maison Liban
> focused their efforts on creating wards against divination in order to
> prevent their discovery.
>
> The surviving members in modern nights are known for the paths of
> Counter Magic (Parma Magicka) Protection from Scrying and Divination,
> and Summoning Binding/Warding.

I understand why they did it and hid back then in the start - with the House Tremere eventually taking a "become undead or dead" approach to it's members, as well as the surviving mortal mages who defected being forced by the Order of Hermes into surveillance and into joining House Ex Miscellanea (presumably who became Maison Liban fleeing that too, out of respect/preservation for their own House's *non-vampiric* ways/practices or something like that); but it's been centuries now.

The Order of Hermes and House - now *Clan* - Tremere have both got other, much bigger things to deal with right now and have diverged a lot since: so, it's not like the Maison Liban with it's knowledge of original Order/House ways is going to know any dangerous modern secrets.

**So, based on what might be indicated by canon lore, is their anything that actually indicates whether them still hiding even in Modern Nights is actually even genuinley *necessary anymore?***

**As in, if either of the factions they hide from found out about them, would there be any repercussions of that discovery? Or are the fears of the Maison Liban misplaced in the era of the 21st century?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Tremere?  Maybe not.  Order of Hermes?  Definitely not.**

The Order of Hermes these days has issues large enough that if anything, the Maison Liban would look like natural allies.  For that matter, they're part of the Traditions now, which means that they've had to accustom themselves to working with the likes of the Euthanatos, the Dreamspeakers, and the Celestial Chorus.  They're also in a position where if they start going too jack-booted on potential allies, the other traditions are likely to start objecting a bit, and have enough political influence to make that mean something.  At worst, they might get annoyingly pushy on the recruitment offers and evangelism attempts.

The Tremere?  It kind of depends.  The more recent Tremere won't care, but they are by nature not at the top of that vampire hierarchy.  The Tremere who are old enough to have started out as House Tremere may well have a few members who cherish a particularly personal bit of bitterness about the Maison Laiban and/or fear their inevitable retribution.  Old vampires get a bit crazy sometimes.  It's true that Clan Tremere has bigger things to deal with, but that's because the Maison Laiban is relatively small.  If some appropriately old and powerful Tremere decides that that particular group of mages needs to get wiped out, then the Maison Laiban is going to have a bad day.  It all depends on whether the upper management of the clan went crazy in ways that make them care about a particular centuries-old grudge or not care about a particular centuries-old grudge.

**But they don't necessarily know that.**

One of the hallmarks of the World of Darkness is how little individual groups actually know about what's going on in other groups.  If the Maison Laiban has been deliberately keeping their heads down as hard as they can, there's a good chance that all they know is that the Tremere vampires were hunting them, the Order of Hermes mages were trying to force them to give up their traditions, and both groups are still out there thriving in the modern world.  That's plenty of reason to keep on keeping your head down... especially since the group will tend to recruit from potential new mages who are naturally inclined think that keeping your head down and hiding all the time is totally the plan.

**And there are other reasons to hide.**

The Technocracy is out there.  That's only the most obvious threat in a world that's *full* of them.  You have the Technocracy, a wide variety of wyrmspawn and wyrm-tainted, many if not most of the Vampires, and a decent fraction of the werewolves, at bare minimum.  If you are a smallish faction of mages with a non-Technocracy-friendly paradigm and limited knowledge of the outside world, then keeping yourself hidden is probably a good idea, especially if that's the strategy that your faction has been honing and perfecting for the last few centuries.

Comment: "If some appropriately old and powerful Tremere decides that that particular group of mages needs to get wiped out, then the Maison Laiban is going to have a bad day." I think it's more likely that the vampire's gonna have a bad day, when the mages start throwing around conjured sunlight like candy. ;)

Comment: @nick012000 It depends. Mages have vastly more flexible powers in a straight head-to-head fight. Vampires, especially the Tremere, tend to avoid straight head-to-head fights, and a mage that is taken by surprise is very squishy.

Comment: @nick012000 "The surviving members in modern nights are known for the paths of Counter Magic (Parma Magicka) Protection from Scrying and Divination, and Summoning Binding/Warding."  That's not the "throwing around sunlight like candy" kind of mage, for the most part.  They're also a relatively small group, which means that their powerful mages are going to be relatively few and far between.  Sure, for any vampire power out there, you can come up with a way that some mage can counter it... but that doesn't mean that all, most, or many mages will have that technique.  The day will still be bad.